# Capacitor-charging parallel circuit and given current

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, transient

Given is a parallel circuit in which one branch consists of a capacitor C with a resistor R1 and the other branch consists of a resistor R2. See the image:

[image]

If we apply a known voltage \$U_{tot}\$ between the two ends (marked as rings) we would have the capacitor charging. The current through R1 over time would be \$ I_{R1}(t) = \frac{U_{tot}}{R_1} e^{- \frac{t}{R_1 C}}\$, while the current through R2 is \$ I_{R2}(t) = \frac{U_{tot}}{R2}\$. Together they sum up to \$ I_{tot}(t) =  I_{R1}(t) + I_{R2}(t)\$

My question is: Is there an analytical solution for \$ I_{R2}(t)\$ for the case when we apply **a constant total current instead of voltage**. So \$ I_{tot}(t) = const.\$ and \$ U_{tot}\$ can variate depending on how the capacitor is charged already.

Since even the initial condition for the charging of the capacitor with \$ \frac{\delta U_{tot}}{dt} = 0\$ is not met, I do not know how \$ I_{R1}(t) \$ should look like in order to get \$ I_{R2}(t)\$ by Kirchhoffs law.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Notice that we can apply KCL in the first place:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\underbrace{\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}\left(t\right)}_{=\space\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Using the voltage and current relations in resistors and capacitors we can write:

- $$\text{V}_{\text{R}_1}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_1\tag2$$
- $$\text{V}_{\text{R}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_2\tag3$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{C}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}\tag4$$

It is not hard to see also that:

- $$\text{V}_{\text{R}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_{\text{R}_1}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)\tag5$$
- $$\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)\tag6$$

Using this information and assuming that \$\$ is a constant DC-current, you can show that:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{in}\left(1-\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{C}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\right)\right)\tag7$$

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer. All the initial conditions 1) to 6) make sense and I was able to derive your final result!

Comment: @pythusiast I'm glad that you liked it and that my answer helped you. You're 100% welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a theoretical solution.

Voltage over R2 is equal to voltage over R1+Voltage over Capacitor.  Currents total overall current.  Capacitor voltage over time is a function of initial charge and current that passes through capacitor.

```
R2*I2 = Vc+ R1*I1
I= I1+I2
dVc/dt = I1/C
```

```
Vc = R2*I-(R2+R1)*I1
dVc/dt = I1/C = -(R2+R1)dI1/dt
...
I1 = -(R2+R1)*C dI1/dt
```

Capacitor charges up (or discharges if it happened to be charged), current through R1 goes to 0 as time passes and you get I2 = I at t=inf.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there an analytical solution for \$I_{R2}(t)\$ for the case when we
> apply a constant total current instead of voltage.*

Try this: -

[image]

- Then solve the voltage source problem to give you current through R1
  and C \$\tag{1}\$.
- Then solve the voltage across R1 and C \$\tag{2}\$
- Use solution (2) to calculate current through R2 as if it were it parallel with R1 and C (as originally shown)

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple.

It's a first order circuit so for any quantity involved you just need initial value, final value and time constant.

In this case, exciting with a constant current we have:

- IR2(0+)=I R1/(R1+R2) by current divider rule with C acting as a short circuit.
- IR2(infty)=I by capacitor being an open circuit in regime conditions.
- tau=C(R1+R2) using the resistance seen by the capacitor .

Now put all together writing an exponential from IR2(0+) to IR2(infty) with tau time constant.